# Visual Studio 2008 Form1 textbox1.text renames Form2 label1.Text

Tags: forms, visual-studio-2008

We're having a problem on how to transfer data from one form to another by clicking a button.

Tried codes like "Form3 (label1.Text = Form1 (Textbox1.Text))" thru Trial and Error but at this point I'm at the roadblock

I hope you guys still remember the code for this... Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you aware that VS2008 is 15 years old?

Comment: Trust me, even the school is aware but man they can't even upgrade their PCs to the point our prof had to make us use it instead of a later version that our PCs at home supports